# The logic behind `np.nanargmin([np.nan, np.inf]) = 0`

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I understand that `np.nanargmin` finds the smallest number in a list that is not a NaN. However if called upon the array `[np.nan, np.inf]` it yields `0` which is a NaN. I find this behavior rather odd and am just wondering what the logic in defining `np.argmin` this way.

Comment: This *is* mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.nanargmin.html) - "Warning: the results cannot be trusted if a slice contains only NaNs and Infs" - though documented or not, it's still surprising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for `np.nanargmin` it says:

> Warning: the results cannot be trusted if a slice contains only NaNs and Infs.

If you view the source code it has the following line:

```
a, mask = _replace_nan(a, np.inf)
```

So it is replacing all `nan` occurrences with `inf`, and so then it is finding the min (still a bit questionable), which will be `argmin([inf, inf])`.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the [source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.13.0/numpy/lib/nanfunctions.py#L366-L407) you see:

```
a, mask = _replace_nan(a, np.inf)
res = np.argmin(a, axis=axis)
```

meaning that it's replacing `np.nan` with `np.inf`.  Since `np.argmin` for repeated values returns the first instance of that value, `np.argmin([np.inf, np.inf])` returns `0`